# What's the right way to enrich a message, with content from a service, using camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm using camel 2.10.3, with the Spring DSL.

I'm monitoring a directory for a CSV file. Each file contains information about where to go download something, along with other meta data - who requested it etc..

I consume the file, and now I want to use the HTTPComponent to download the entity referenced in the file and then save that to disk (to be processed later), something like this:

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:/incoming"/>
  <unmarshall ref="csv"/>
  <recipientList><simple>${in.body[1]}</simple></recipientList>
  <to uri="file:/attachemnts"/>
  <to ref="furtherProcessing"/>
</route>
```

I'm using recipientList because the URL is dynamic based on the content of the CSV file. The above doesn't work because the HTTPComponent tries to send the in.body of the exchange (which is the value of the CSV file contents) to the HTTP service.

I need the values from the CSV file later on in processing so I can't just blow them away. My first attempt at solving this was to move all the values from the CSV file into headers and then set the body to null so that the HTTPComponent won't complain (even if it didn't complain, I still need to somehow preserve the original CSV data). This works but really clutters up the route, there are lots of headers and I have to manually copy each one.

Seems like I need to have some kind of side route to do the download, I thought about using multicast with a custom aggregationStrategy, then with one endpoint being the download, the other being a no-op, but this didn't seem that clean either.

Anyone have any advice on how do this this cleanly, I feel like I'm missing something really simple?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand your case, you have URLs in the CSV file that you need to do a HTTP/GET operation towards without any payload data in the request.

I would copy the body of the message into an exchange property. Since the unmarshalled content is a `List<List<String>>`, you can set it into a property, then get it back later from that property as a whole.

Something like this (I did not really test it, so beware of syntax type-os).

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:/incoming"/>
  <unmarshall ref="csv"/>
  <setProperty propertyName="originalData">  
     <simple>${body}</simple>  
  </setProperty>
  <setBody>
     <simple>null</simple><!-- will make HTTP use GET method and not send data -->
  </setBody>
  <recipientList><simple>${in.property.originalData[1]}</simple></recipientList>
  <to uri="file:/attachemnts"/>
  <to ref="furtherProcessing"/>
</route>
```

Comment: Thanks Petter, I hadn't thought of putting the whole thing in an exchange property - certainly makes that cleaner.